# How to use "apt-get" via "Http-proxy" like this?

Tags: apt, internet, proxy, synaptic, authentication

I'm trying to use `apt-get` command on a network that uses a proxy, like this:

We use 10.114.7.7 on port 80 as Http-proxy, and after that an authentication window comes up, asking for user name and password.

Our Username/Domain is like this: **username@urmia.ac.ir**

I'm wondering, how i can use `http_proxy=http://User:Pass@Proxyserver:Port` in this situation!?
I also tried both, 10.114.7.7 and urmia.ac.ir as Proxy server but no result!

Answer (score 41):

To use apt-get through a proxy, either make a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` called proxy or something that you'll recognise, or make (if it doesn't exist) `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and insert the following line:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxy.server:port/";
```

Simply replace username and password with your login details, and replace proxy.server:port with the correct address (in your case, 10.114.7.7:80), so your line will end up something like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@10.114.7.7:80";
```

If you're required to use the `@` symbol in your username, you'll have to escape it with a backslash (`username@urmia.ac.ir`)

While escaping characters by using the backlash does not work (e.g. `\@` in `export` and `wget`), special characters can be escaped with URL encoding. For instance, `username:my@pass@server.com:port` becomes `username:my%40pass@server.com:port`. See this [list of URL-encoded characters](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php) for more information.

Comment: The proposed solution for adding a proxy entry inside /etc/apt worked for me, but I note that if your proxy server caches credentials, you can avoid embedding your credentials in the configuration file by simply authenticating through your proxy server in a different process (e.g. web browser in Windows), prior to running the apt commands in your bash shell. By doing this I was able to specify the proxy entry inside /etc/apt as "http://server:port" instead of "http://username:password@server:port".

Comment: P.S. Don't forget that semicolon `;` (not to be as silly as me)

Answer (score 8):

This should solve your problem:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@10.114.7.7:80/
```

Comment: `EXPORT HTTP_proxy=http://username:password@10.114.7.7:80/` run in Bash results in `EXPORT: command not found`.

Comment: Both export and http in lower case. Bash is case-sensitive. Else it should work. At least it has been working for me for two years.

Comment: works for curl, but not for apt.

Comment: For me it worked for apt-get like this. Note tho, it needs to be "http_proxy" not "HTTP_PROXY". Some programs accept both, apt-get seems to only accept the former.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can place the following in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy.server.port:8080";
```

8080 is the port number and I think is standard.

Don't forget the quotes or the trailing semicolon.